# Determine the number of zeros in the first quadrant

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, roots

This is a homework question:

$$f(z) = z^2 - z + 1$$

sorry for the poor code!

Answer (score 1):

The zeros can be computed by quadratic formula, yield 
$z=\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{3}i$. Thus the number of zeros on the first quadrant is one, that is, $z=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{3}i$.

Comment: But how do you solve it if you want to use a complex plane?

Comment: Just using the quadratic formula and $z=\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{3}i$ is on the second quadrant

Comment: I understand that argument, but what if you wanted to solve it by splitting the quarter circle into 3 paths: (1) along the x-axis _0 < x < R_ (2) the arc from 0 to pi/2 and (3)along the y-axis to the origin.

Comment: @user142024: You can do this, but you need to show that $f$ does not have a zero on the contour and then presumably use the argument principle to compute the number of enclosed zeros. Performing the integration is a lot more work than using the quadratic formula...

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the zeroes for this quadratic polynomial is 1.  Since the polynomial has real coefficients, the zeroes must be complex conjugates $ \ a \pm bi \ $ .  So we have the sum $ \ 2a = 1 \ \Rightarrow \ a = \frac{1}{2} \ $ , which tells us that the zeroes lie in the first and fourth quadrants; the fact that they are conjugates places one in each of those quadrants.

(Just to eliminate the possibility that the zeroes might be on the real axis, the product of the roots, $ \ a^2 + b^2 \ $ , is also 1 , so $ \ b \neq \ 0 \ $ . )